# separate() in tidyr with NA

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a question related to `separate()` in the [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) package. When there is no NA in a data frame, separate() works. I have been using this function a lot. But, today I had a case in which there were NAs in a data frame. `separate()` returned an error message. I could be very silly. But, I wonder if [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) may not be designed for this kind of data cleaning. Or is there any way `separate()` can work with NAs? Thank you very much for taking your time.

Here is an updated sample based on the comments. Say I want to separate characters in y and create new columns. If I remove the row with NA, `separate()` will work. But, I do not want to delete the row, what could I do?

```
x <- c("a-1","b-2","c-3")
y <- c("d-4","e-5", NA)
z <- c("f-6", "g-7", "h-8")

foo <- data.frame(x,y,z, stringsAsFactors = F)

ana <- foo %>%
   separate(y, c("part1", "part2"))

# > foo
#    x    y   z
# 1 a-1  d-4 f-6
# 2 b-2  e-5 g-7
# 3 c-3 <NA> h-8
# > ana <- foo %>%
# +        separate(y, c("part1", "part2"))
# Error: Values not split into 2 pieces at 3
```

Comment: NA should be better used without quotes. Don't know if it is a mistake or not. (Though, it is unrelated to the question).  What is your expected output when there is 'NA'?

Comment: It is good that you updated.  But, I have a doubt.  do you want to separate `y` in to `'part1` with `d, e`, `part2` with 4,5`, and `part3` with NA.  You could have used `foo <- data.frame(x,y,z,stringsAsFactors=F)` and avoid those 4 steps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I changed "NA" to NA in the updated example. If `separate()` can create two NAs after the operation (i.e, one NA in a new column, and another NA in another new column, that would be great. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please file a bug report on the tidyr github?

Comment: Hi Hadley, sure. I just want to make sure that I am supposed to report this under 'Issues' in the tidyr github, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be:

```
    res <- foo %>% 
    mutate(y=ifelse(is.na(y), paste0(NA,"-", NA), y)) %>% 
    separate(y, c('part1', 'part2'))
     res[res=='NA'] <- NA
    res
    #   x part1 part2   z
   #1 a-1     d     4 f-6
   #2 b-2     e     5 g-7
   #3 c-3  <NA>  <NA> h-8
```

Comment: I see. That achieves the goal. You need to have one operation before using `separate()`. Got it. But it would be great if we can avoid that `mutate()` step. I may be too greedy. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @jazzurro.  I would try for that.  If I find something, will update.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `extra` option in `separate`.

Here's an example from [hadley's github issue page](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/commit/d2ded57af23fc348d0af910ae1831097d637b8cc)

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a b", "a b c", NA))
> df
      x
1     a
2   a b
3 a b c
4  <NA>
> df %>% separate(x, c("a", "b"), extra = "merge")
     a    b
1    a <NA>
2    a    b
3    a  b c
4 <NA> <NA>
> df %>% separate(x, c("a", "b"), extra = "drop")
     a    b
1    a <NA>
2    a    b
3    a    b
4 <NA> <NA>
```